# White font turns to black when opening a SVG in Inkscape v1.2

Tags: svg, inkscape

[So I have this magical SVG from my school on my github.](https://github.com/zhtluo/purdue-slide-template/blob/main/logo/cs-rev.svg)

When I preview it on Github, it has a white font. When I open it in Inkscape v0.92, it has a white font.

However, when I try to open it in Inkscape v1.2, it has a black font.

I suspect the SVG might be malformed somehow, but I read the file and it seemed normal to me so I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Don't see nothing "malformed" in your file either. However I can't help but notice that the class pattern makes it actually use more bytes than if it was just inlined on all the elements ;-) Do you know which software did produce it?

Comment: @Kaiido I got it from my school so idk :(

Comment: @Kaiido's recommendation to shorten the class names will in fact fix the problem. Apparently inkscape tries to decode the octet `e312f32b` as a hex code - find/replace class `e312f32b-8359-4032-a3ee-970370572371` with something like `wht`. (prefixing will also solve the problem).

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Inkscape v1.2, in v1.02 it also works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the phenomenon was a bug:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3921

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).